# Apply javascript to html injected with AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, zurb-foundation

I am creating a portfolio site that I'd like pull in partial HTML files through an AJAX request. This is the basic HTML:

```
    <div id="portfolio">
      // This will be replaced
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="fire">Click Me</a>
```

The jquery code that I am using looks like this:

```
    $( "#fire" ).click(function() {
        $( "#portfolio" ).load("partial.html #portfolio > *");
    });
```

This works, and I'm able to load the individual partial pages, but I cannot figure out how to have scripts run on the inserted HTML. I'm using Foundation Orbit, and I want to have these sliders function properly after the AJAX call. I thought maybe it was a conflict, so I also tried using slides.js, but that didn't work either. I have all the dependencies and needed scripts in my index file. What do I need to do to have the Orbit script apply to content on the page after the AJAX call?

I have a functioning plunkr that shows the problem I'm having. I'm just learning all this, so apologies if there is a super obvious answer, but I haven't found it on the site.

Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/BZQxw6PlmfFq1WOkIADS). It has a working Orbit slider to prove -- to myself -- that the script is working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What code isn't working on the dynamically loaded HTML?  If it involves something like initializing a plugin on an element (or set of elements) then you'd need to re-initialize on any elements added afterward.

Comment: @Bamar -- this question does not duplicate the referenced question. There is a specific javascript call related to Foundation Orbit, there is no "live" version of the plugin.

Comment: It's a basic slider that is brought in. I guess it's re-initializing the element that I don't understand. @Barmar believes this is a duplicate question, but I'm not sure I understand the answer in that question... How do I re-initialize something, or what does that mean exactly. Sorry: beginner.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, I thought you were trying to bind an event handler. For initializing plugins, you have to do it in the AJAX callback function.

Comment: I've reopened the question.

Comment: @Barmar -- now HERE is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111624/how-to-dynamically-load-foundation-orbit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a callback function, which is an optional argument for `load()`

```
$( "#portfolio" ).load("partial.html #portfolio > *", function (response) {
    // executed after query is complete
});
```

After you add a new Orbit slider to the page, you will have to initialize it:

```
$(document).foundation('orbit').init();
```

... so, you'd do that in your callback function.

**Documentation**

- `jQuery.load` - http://api.jquery.com/load/
- Foundation Orbit - http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked. Really appreciate how fast you answered. Sorry I can't upvote -- just joined.

Comment: @gushags No problem! When an answer (or question) is marked "community wiki", it means that the answerer has opted out of reputation gain from upvotes, so it really isn't a concern :)